# How to show navigation arrows in amp carousel in mobile

Tags: android, jquery, css, amp-html

I want to show navigation arrows in amp carousel in mobile but by default it does not show arrows. I have tried `.amp-carousel-button { display:""; }` and many others but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 5):

You could also simply add the attribute `controls` to the `<amp-carousel>` tag, along with the other options you pass in.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
.amp-carousel-button {

   opacity: 1;

   visibility: visible;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The amp-carousel navigation arrows are not visible all the time in mobile by default but on the desktop, arrows are always displayed unless only a single child is present (according to the official docs) https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components/amp-carousel#controls-(optional). This is a bug which needs to be fixed. Nothing can be done about it right now

Comment: You could also simply add the attribute controls to the <amp-carousel> tag, along with the other options you pass in. below answer helped to fix it.